# context for each type of ebpf program

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf

I've seen that for each type of ebpf program there is a different input (context) to the program. For example in the case of a BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER program  a pointer to struct __sk_buff is passed as an argument.
Where are defined  the contexts for each program type  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where are defined the contexts for each program type?

There are defined in the kernel, generally in the kernel headers. The precise location depends on the program type. For example, `__sk_buff` is used by several program types and is defined in [`linux/bpf.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2.10/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L2894).

To find which context each program is expecting, you can look at BPF samples in the kernel or try to find the `xxxx_convert_ctx_access` for a given program type. These functions translate accesses to the context object into accesses to the actual kernel object (for example, `__sk_buff` is a mirror to `sk_buff`). As an example, [XDP programs expect a context of type `struct xdp_md`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2.10/source/net/core/filter.c#L7549).

As pointed out by @Qeole in comments, there's a blog post by Oracle, from January 2019, that [lists the expected context for each program type](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/notes-on-bpf-1).

Comment: Good answer. As a complement, [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/notes-on-bpf-1) lists the contexts for all the (then existing) program types and may be of interest.

Comment: Ah, great! I've added it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: In the article about BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT it's written "What context is provided? The context provided by the specific tracepoint; arguments and data types are associated with the tracepoint definition."
Within /include/trace/events/syscalls.h there is 
TRACE_EVENT_FN(sys_enter,

        TP_PROTO(struct pt_regs *regs, long id),

        TP_ARGS(regs, id),

        TP_STRUCT__entry(
                __field(        long,           id              )
                __array(        unsigned long,  args,   6       )
        ),
....
Ho can I exactly understand which is the context?

Comment: And also. I've seen here https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/06821504fd47a5e5b641aeeb638a0ae10a216ef8/tools/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L3430-L3432 there is bpf_raw_tracepoint_args defined which is used with raw_tracepoint programs. But I can't find the context for just tracepoint .

Comment: For tracepoints, the context structure is specific to each probe site (e.g., `block:block_getrq` and `block:block_plug` will have different context structures). See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47031794/6884590) for how to get the content of each structure. You will have to declare that structure yourself with the appropriate fields (though [bcc does that for you](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/270d54ae18c589b352dad71f465cf7d439275e24/src/cc/frontends/clang/tp_frontend_action.cc#L137)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, after looking around I was reading that in this example https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/xdp_redirect_cpu_kern.c#L572-L584. Anyway I'd like to understand how I can build the structure starting from the format output. In my case the output of  /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_open/format . Because usually I don't see a 1 to 1 mapping , as I've seen between this /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/power/cpu_idle/format (6 fields)  and https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/cpustat_kern.c (here the struct has 3 fields)