# Read eBPF tracepoint argument

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

Assume that I have a tracepoint eBPF probe that hooks into the chown function.

```
SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_chown")
int bpf_prog(void *ctx) {
  // someone changed ownership of a file
  char msg[] = "Ownership change of file!";
  bpf_trace_printk(msg, sizeof(msg));
}
```

How can I access the context of the call? For example, what if I want to print out the file that changed ownership or the new owner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR.** In the case of `sys_enter_chown`, your `ctx` argument will have the structure:

```
struct syscalls_enter_chown_args {
    unsigned long long unused;
    long syscall_nr;
    long filename_ptr;
    long user;
    long group;
};
```

---

As pointed by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47031794/6884590), tracepoint hooks are documented in the kernel. You can find the full description of `sys_enter_chown`'s arguments at `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_chown/format`:

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_chown/format 
name: sys_enter_chown
ID: 625
format:
    field:unsigned short common_type;   offset:0;   size:2; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_flags;   offset:2;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;   offset:3;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:int common_pid;   offset:4;   size:4; signed:1;

    field:int __syscall_nr; offset:8;   size:4; signed:1;
    field:const char * filename;    offset:16;  size:8; signed:0;
    field:uid_t user;   offset:24;  size:8; signed:0;
    field:gid_t group;  offset:32;  size:8; signed:0;

print fmt: "filename: 0x%08lx, user: 0x%08lx, group: 0x%08lx", ((unsigned long)(REC->filename)), ((unsigned long)(REC->user)), ((unsigned long)(REC->group))
```

You can also check [the sample BPF tracepoint program](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/418baf2c28f3473039f2f7377760bd8f6897ae18/samples/bpf/syscall_tp_kern.c) in the kernel samples. It implements what you're looking for, but for `sys_enter_open`.